Itterows not populating as expected
I have a pandas dataframe of scores:
data_1 = {"Grad_22": [96, np.nan, np.nan], "Grad_23": [92, 97, np.nan], "Grad_24": [np.nan, 93, 95]}
df_1= pd.DataFrame(data_1)
df_1["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(["2022-12-31","2023-12-31","2024-12-31"])
df_1.set_index("DATE", inplace=True)

            Grad_22  Grad_23  Grad_24
DATE                                 
2022-12-31     96.0     92.0      NaN
2023-12-31      NaN     97.0     93.0
2024-12-31      NaN      NaN     95.0


I also have a dataframe of grads by years:
data_2 = {
    "Sr": ["Grad_22","Grad_23"],
    "Jr": ["Grad_23","Grad_24"]
}
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)
df_2["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(["2022-12-31","2023-12-31"])
df_2.set_index("DATE", inplace=True)

                 Sr       Jr
DATE                        
2022-12-31  Grad_22  Grad_23
2023-12-31  Grad_23  Grad_24

I would like to use the rows from df_2 as labels for df_1 to populate df_3
data_3= {"Sr": [0, 0], "Jr": [0, 0]}
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(data_3)
df_3 ["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(["2022-12-31","2023-12-31"])
df_3.set_index("DATE", inplace=True)
print(df_3)
'''



Iterrows seems perfect for this:

'''
for index, row in df_2.iterrows():
    df_3.loc[index] = df_1.loc[index, row] 
print(df_3)

I would expect:
                Sr       Jr
DATE                        
2022-12-31  96.0  92.0
2023-12-31  97.0  93.0


Instead, i get:
                Sr       Jr
DATE              
2022-12-31 NaN NaN
2023-12-31 NaN NaN

How should I be assigning to df_3 and why am I getting NaN?

Just use df_3.loc[index] = df_1.loc[index, row].values

The reason is simple, because your indices are not aligned on the columns.
You would have needed to use the underlying numpy array:
df_3 = df_2.copy()

for index, row in df_2.iterrows():
    df_3.loc[index] = df_1.loc[index, row].values

For a more pandas-aware approach, you can reshape with melt, merge, and pivot:
df_3 = (df_2
  .melt(ignore_index=False, var_name='col', value_name='variable')
  .reset_index()
  .merge(df_1.melt(ignore_index=False).reset_index())
  .pivot(index='DATE', columns='col', values='value')
  .reindex_like(df_2)
)

Output:
              Sr    Jr
DATE                  
2022-12-31  96.0  92.0
2023-12-31  97.0  93.0

